# AS3 ArgumentError: Error #1063: Expected 0, got 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

Can anyone can help me with this issue.
I have no idea with this issue.
Just keep getting this issue.
Already try modify from this

`function init(e:Event = null)` to `function init()` or `function init(e:Event)`

Appreciated who can help me with this.
If no issue on this, it should show food not my stage.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        var snake:Array;
        var score:Number;

        public function Main() {
            // constructor code
            if(stage)
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            else
                init();
        }

        function init(e:Event = null):void {
            //initialize
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

        }

        function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
            var food:Food = new Food();
            this.addChild(food);
            trace("food");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Enable permit debugging from options, so you can get the line of the error. Now it's not sure which function gets the error. The only ones without parameter in your case are `Main` and `Food`, both classes....

Comment: Your code looks fine, I think that you got that error because you have used `function init():void{}` which normaly will fire that error when used with `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct.
Replace `if (stage)` to `if (!stage)`.
If error still happens attach FLA.